# C# Switch and Count Substring Match

Tags: c#, .net

Trying to count the occurrences of specific lines in a file by their record type which is the first character of the line.  My total line count is correct, and my "Other" count is correct but my switch results don't total the line counts.  The foreach is running 13 times, but the counts aren't updating.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
int i1LineCount = 0;
int i2LineCount = 0;
int i3LineCount = 0;
int i4LineCount = 0;
int iOther = 0;
int iCount = File.ReadLines(@"c:\single.txt").Count();

foreach (string line in File.ReadLines(@"c:\single.txt"))
{
String sFirstChar = line.Substring(0, 1);
switch (sFirstChar)
{
    case "1":
    i1LineCount = i1LineCount+1;
    break;
    case "2":
    i2LineCount = i2LineCount+1;
    break;
    case "3":
    i3LineCount = i3LineCount+1;
    break;
    case "4":
    i4LineCount = i4LineCount+1;
    break;
    default:
    iOther = iOther+1;
    break;
}
}
Console.WriteLine("Line Count = " + iCount);
Console.WriteLine("1 lines = " + i1LineCount);
Console.WriteLine("2 lines = " + i1LineCount);
Console.WriteLine("3 lines = " + i1LineCount);
Console.WriteLine("4 lines = " + i1LineCount);
Console.WriteLine("Other lines = " + iOther);
}
```

The txt file I'm reading looks like (without the ' in front of #, I couldn't make it show up without it):

> ```
> '#  
> \  
> 1  
> 4  
> 4  
> 2  
> 2  
> 2  
> 3  
> 2  
> 4  
> 4  
> '#
> ```

**The results I'm getting are**:

```
Line Count = 13  
1 lines = 1  
2 lines = 1  
3 lines = 1  
4 lines = 1  
Other lines = 3
```

**I should be getting**:

```
Line Count = 13  
1 lines = 1  
2 lines = 4  
3 lines = 1  
4 lines = 4  
Other lines = 3
```

Comment: Your output code is wrong, it prints `i1LineCount` for all line types.

Comment: Yup, that's an embarassing answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are writing out `i1LineCount` 4 times.

Code should be:

```
Console.WriteLine("Line Count = " + iCount);
Console.WriteLine("1 lines = " + i1LineCount);
Console.WriteLine("2 lines = " + i2LineCount);
Console.WriteLine("3 lines = " + i3LineCount);
Console.WriteLine("4 lines = " + i4LineCount);
Console.WriteLine("Other lines = " + iOther);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're printing out the count of the `1` lines each time:

```
Console.WriteLine("Line Count = " + iCount);
Console.WriteLine("1 lines = " + i1LineCount);
Console.WriteLine("2 lines = " + i1LineCount);
Console.WriteLine("3 lines = " + i1LineCount);
Console.WriteLine("4 lines = " + i1LineCount);
Console.WriteLine("Other lines = " + iOther);
```

You need to print out i2, i3, i4, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Check your Console.WriteLines...

```
Console.WriteLine("Line Count = " + iCount);
Console.WriteLine("1 lines = " + i1LineCount);
Console.WriteLine("2 lines = " + i1LineCount);
Console.WriteLine("3 lines = " + i1LineCount);
Console.WriteLine("4 lines = " + i1LineCount);
Console.WriteLine("Other lines = " + iOther);
```

should be...

```
Console.WriteLine("Line Count = " + iCount);
Console.WriteLine("1 lines = " + i1LineCount);
Console.WriteLine("2 lines = " + i2LineCount);
Console.WriteLine("3 lines = " + i3LineCount);
Console.WriteLine("4 lines = " + i4LineCount);
Console.WriteLine("Other lines = " + iOther);
```

Answer (score 0):

You printing `i1LineCount` all the time you probably need this:

```
Console.WriteLine("Line Count = " + iCount);
Console.WriteLine("1 lines = " + i1LineCount);
Console.WriteLine("2 lines = " + i2LineCount);
Console.WriteLine("3 lines = " + i3LineCount);
Console.WriteLine("4 lines = " + i4LineCount);
Console.WriteLine("Other lines = " + iOther);
```

Also I would suggest to use arrays.